# How to add score counter to python rock paper scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

name = input("What is your name?")
print ("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors", name, "!")

def computerThrow():
    throwOptions = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
    randomChoice = random.randint(0,2)
    return throwOptions [randomChoice]

def playerThrow():
  player = input("rock, paper, scissors?")
  return player

def compareThrows(player, computer):
  if player == computer:
    return("tie")
  elif player == "rock":
    if computer == "scissors":
      return("win")
    else:
      return("lose")
  elif player == "scissors":
    if computer == "paper":
      return("win")
    else:
      return("lose")
  elif player == "paper":
    if computer == "rock":
      return("win")
    else:
      return("lose")
  else:
      return("invalid")

def printMatchOutcome(result, player, computer):
  if result == "win":
    print(player, "beats", computer, " — You win!")
  if result == "lose":
    print (computer,"beats",player, "- You lose!")
  if result == "tie":
    print("tie match!")
  if result == "invalid":
    print ("invalid...try again")

def oneRound():
  player = playerThrow()
  print("You threw:",player)

  computer = computerThrow()
  print("Computer threw:",computer)

  compare = compareThrows(player, computer)
  printMatchOutcome(compare, player, computer)

#define counter variable
gamesPlayed = 0
playerWins = 0
computerWins = 0

userWantsToPlay = True
while userWantsToPlay:
    oneRound()
    response = input("Do you want to play again? (yes / no)")
    if response == 'yes':
      userWantsToPlay = True
    else:
      userWantsToPlay = False
print("Thanks for playing!")


def score(result):
  oneRound()
  if result == "win":
    return playerWins + 1
  elif result == "lose":
    return computerWins + 1
```

I am trying to add a score counter to my game so that once userWantsToPlay = False it will display the number of games played, and the score for the computer and the player. I have started it as a function but I am not sure if that is even right? How would I go about this?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. Also there is no reason for all of those return statements.

Comment: Create a counter a counter for the player and the computer. Each time the player wins increment the player's counter by one, and visa vera for the computer. At the end of your program, print the value of the player's counter and the computer's counter.